# YAML object keys list

Tags: ansible, yaml

I've got this yaml object

`users:
  user1: some description
  user2: another desc
  user3: ...`

How can I get this object's keys? Result should be `[user1, user2, user3]`

EDIT: I'm using yaml variables in `ansible`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @blhsing I'm using `ansible`

Comment: That is not a YAML object, it is a YAML document. It consists of a root-level mapping which has one key/value pair and that value again is a mapping (and you are interested in the keys of that mapping). There is no such thing as a YAML variable. Since ansible is written in Python the object probably has attributes instead of keys. If you just make up terminology instead of putting in some effort to learn to use the domain relevant lingo, we are less likely to understand what you are asking and less likely to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for valuable info. I ignored `ansible` word when I searched this title from internet and I couldn't find anything. I had to search something like `ansible dictionary keys list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array:

```
{{ users.keys() }}
```

Task:

```
- name: with_dict
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

Template:

```
{% for key, value in users.iteritems() %}
    {{ key|e }}: {{ value|e }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ansible uses Jinja, so you can do:

```
[ {{ obj.keys() | join(", ") }} ]
```